What is the least specialized tissue in plants?
According to me, the answer to this question  is meristematic tissue. Meristems have undifferentiated cells and they are totipotent. Even permanent tissues are formed from meristems.
However, while searching this up in the internet, I found out that most of the sites mentioned parenchyma as the least specialized tissue. https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/where-is-the-least-specialized-tissue-located-in-plants/
Although parenchyma is a ground tissue and it perform versatile functions, I don't agree with this.
I would be very grateful to anyone who would clarify my doubt. Thanks.

Why bother defining some tissue as "least specialized"? How would you objectively define something like that?

@Bryan Krause This question has once been asked in a class test.

I think this is a stupid question expecting you to learn by rote memorization some facts given to you in a class rather than having any actual meaning in biology. I'm sorry you're experiencing such a course. Asking for where the least differentiated tissues are would be a reasonable biology question and I'd agree with you that you have the right answer, but it doesn't seem that's the question being asked.

@Bryan Krause Sorry, I don't get why this question is 'stupid' and has no 'actual meaning in biology'. If this question were asked with reference to animals instead of plants, won't it be stem cells?

That would be the other question: asking for the least differentiated tissues would be a reasonable biology question, and yes, for both animals and plants, stem cells, and you might then be asked to identify where those cells exist; in plants, you've identified the meristem. In animals, it would depend on the type of stem cell. But you were asked "least specialized". Maybe in your course they meant "least differentiated" when they asked "least specialized", or else they wanted you to memorize some line in a textbook that said "blah blah parenchyma is the least specialized tissue".
